# Help with a regex that strips out leading white space

Tags: php, html, regex, kohana

I am modifying a core function of the Kohana library, the [text::auto_p()](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/helpers/text#auto_p) function.

The function describes itself as "nl2br() on steroids". Essentially, it provides `<br />` single line breaks, but double line breaks are surrounded with the `<p>` tags.

The limitation I have found with it is that it will but `<br />`s in a `<pre>` element. This will create double new lines, which isn't what I want. I have made a modification to pick up pre elements with a regex, and a callback that will strip out the `<br />` which works alright.

However, the main problem is that I have code samples in my text that gets `auto_p()`'d, and I need to preserve the indentation (for readability). Unfortunately for me, the function strips leading and trailing white space on lines.

Here is the regex that strips leading space

```
$str = preg_replace('~^[ \t]+~m', '', $str);
```

I'm not the best regex guru, but I'm pretty sure that says "Get leading spaces and tabs where there is at least one and replace them with an empty string."

I have tried removing this line, but then it will add `<br />` where I definitely do not want them - in one case, I was getting output like this

```
<ul><br />
    <li>something</li>
</ul>
```

How would I modify this regex or code to not strip leading space inside of a `<pre>` element?

[The original helper function from Kohana is available here](http://source.kohanaphp.com/trunk/system/helpers/text.php). (scroll to the almost bottom).

I know I will get a few 'Use a HTML parser' type answers - and while you may be correct - the existing code simply uses regex, and I would prefer a simpler solution (where I don't have to include a library etc).

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
$str = preg_replace(
    '~^[ \t]++(?=(?:[^<]++|<(?!/?+pre\b))*+(?:\z|<pre\b))~im',
    '', $str);
```

After matching some line-leading whitespace, the lookahead scans ahead for `<pre>` or `</pre>` tags.  The meat of the lookahead is this bit:

```
(?:[^<]++|<(?!/?+pre\b))*+
```

It matches zero or more of anything that's not a left angle bracket, **or** a left angle bracket if it's not the beginning of a `<pre>` or `</pre>` tag.  That part will only stop matching when it encounters a `<pre>` (starting) tag, a `</pre>` (ending) tag, or the end of the input.  If it's an ending tag that stops it, you know you're inside a `<PRE>` element, so you don't want to do the replacement.

The possessive quantifiers (`'++'`, `'*+'`, and `'?+'`) are essential to prevent [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).  (I can't help it: that phrase always makes me think of the *resonance cascade scenario* from [Half-Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-Life_%28video_game%29).)

This technique also assumes reasonably well-formed HTML, i.e., all `<pre>...</pre>` tags properly balanced.  Tags inside of SGML comments will mess it up, too--unless they happen to be balanced.  You can deal with comments, too, if you don't mind making the regex twice as long and three times as ugly. :)

Comment: This is a great answer (I will try it in a moment) +1 for everything (including Half Life reference) :)